# how to move rich modal panel

Tags: richfaces, move, modalpopup

I cannot move modal panel.
  Eventhough i am using   movable="true"  attribute.
I have include one jsp page in that modal panel.

main.jsp

```
<f:view>
   <html>
     <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
     </head>
     <body>
        <h:form id="modalPanelForm">
                <a4j:outputPanel id="outputPanel">
                        <a4j:commandButton value="Show Modal Panel" onclick="#{rich:component('modalPanel')}.show();"/>
                </a4j:outputPanel> 
        </h:form> 
                 <rich:modalPanel id="modalPanel" moveable="true">
                       <f:subview id="jobSchedulerSubView">
                            <jsp:include page="test1.jsp" flush="true"/>
                       </f:subview> 
                 </rich:modalPanel> 

</body></html></f:view>
```

test1.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/a4j" prefix="a4j"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/rich" prefix="rich"%>
  <f:verbatim>
     <html>
        <head>
           <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        </head>
        <body>
  </f:verbatim>
           <h:form id="testForm"> 
               <rich:panel id="testRichPanel"> 
                  <f:facet name="header">
                      <h:outputText value="SecondModalpanel"/>
                  </f:facet> 

                     <a4j:outputPanel id="testOutputPanel">
                          <a4j:commandButton value="Close Modal Panel" 
                                      onclick="#{rich:component('modalPanel')}.hide();"
                                      reRender="modalPanel"/>
                     </a4j:outputPanel> 
               </rich:panel>
</h:form>

<f:verbatim></body></html><f:verbatim>
```

I have so many page like first.jsp, second.jsp, third.jsp , fourth.jsp etc....
Every page have modal panel, and each modal panel include 'test1.jsp' page.
Thats why i am using like

```
<rich:modalpanel ....>             
      <f:subview ....>
          <jsp:include page="test1.jsp" .../> 
      </f:subview>         
</rich:modalpanel>
```

Help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add a header `facet` to your `modalPanel`. The default value of `moveable` attribute is `true` and you don't need to set it to `true` manually.

```
<rich:modalPanel id="modalPanel">
   <f:facet name="header"> 
     <h:panelGroup>
       <h:outputText value="PO-Select Supplier"></h:outputText>
     </h:panelGroup>
   </f:facet>
  ...more.............
</rich:modalPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks prageeth. Now i update my question. I have so many page (Example 100 pages). Each page have modalpanel and included that "test1.jsp" page. As per your idea, i need to put <f:facet ..../> tag in every modalpanel in every page. duplicate code write in more pages. In future, i decide to change the modal panel header, that time i need modifiy the header name in 100 pages. this work will take more time.  I hope you will give some other idea

Comment: Try adding the `<f:facet name="header">` part inside the `test1.jsp` page instead of within the `<rich:modalPanel>` tags.

Comment: If i put that <f:facet.../> part in inside the test1.jsp page, then i can't move modal panel .That is my original problem.

Comment: I think the problem is out of my knowledge. I haven't used `<jsp:include>` tag. But I have used `<ui:include>` without any problem while the `<f:facet name="header">` tag is inside the page (instead of `<rich:modalPanel>` tags). Can't you use `<ui:include>` tag? The namespace is `xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am not using facelet for my application.